# Where exactly does a pointer point?

Tags: c

I'm studying pointers, so forgive me if I'm asking something obvious or stupid.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void var_print(int, int, int*, int*, long int);

int main() {

int a = 0, *pa, b = 0, *pb;
long dist = 0;
pa = &a;
pb = &b;
dist = &b - &a;
var_print(a, b, pa, pb, dist);
printf("\n\n");
return 0;

}

void var_print (int a, int b, int *pa, int *pb, long int dist) {
    printf("\n\nVariable\tValue\t\tAddress\t\t\tPoints to...\t\t&var - pointer-to-var\n\n");
    printf("a\t\t%d\t\t%p\n", a, &a);
    printf("*pa\t\t%d\t\t%p\t\t%p\t\t%d\n", *pa, &pa, pa, (int)(pa-&a));
    printf("b\t\t%d\t\t%p\n", b, &b);
    printf("*pb\t\t%d\t\t%p\t\t%p\t\t%d\n", *pb, &pb, pb, (int)(&b-pb));
    printf("dist\t\t%ld\t\t%p\n", dist, &dist);
}
```

This gives as output something like

```
Variable    Value       Address         Points to...        &var - pointer-to-var

a           0       0x7fffa68aa96c
*pa         0       0x7fffa68aa960      0x7fffa68aa988      7
b           0       0x7fffa68aa968
*pb         0       0x7fffa68aa958      0x7fffa68aa98c      -9
dist        1       0x7fffa68aa950
```

Now, the question is: **Why is the value of pa not equal to the address of a?**

I tried to print explicitly `&a - pa` and **whatever the address I get 7 as a result**.

I understood if I calculate the distance between the addresses of two integers I get it in units of sizeof(int), so that 0x7fffa68aa968 (`b` address) - 0x7fffa68aa96c (`a` address) returns 1, still I can't figure out **why 7 and why the same check on b gives 9**. Both odd numbers, too.

I also tried to define a third pointer `pa2` and assign `pa2 = &a`, as a result I get those funny numbers to become respectively 5 and 7 (suggesting the whole thing has something to do with how the memory is allocated), while `pa` and `pa2` values are equal but still not equal to `&a`.

So, in short: **how does it work?**

Comment: Move all of the `printf`s into `main`, and delete the `var_print` function. Then you'll get sensible answers for everything but `dist`. The `dist` calculation invokes undefined behavior, so there's no guarantee what that will be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int main() {
int a = 0, *pa, b = 0, *pb;
```

Your `main` function defines 4 variables named a, pa, b, and pb.

```
void var_print (int a, int b, int *pa, int *pb, long int dist)
```

Your `var_print` *also has four totally different objects*, that, by sheer chance, also happen to be named a, b, pa, and pb.  They are *initialized* from the values in main, but they are separate objects.

But just because two objects are both named "pa" does not mean they're the same object. This is why the `pa` in `var_print` points at the `a` inside `main`, and not at the `a` inside `var_print`
.